# Create an interface pattern in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, design-patterns, factory-pattern

This is related to pattern design in Python, especially interface building.
I need to implement generic interface to handle call and dispatch into specialized functions.

I have this code:

```
def get_batch(func_name_id="", ddict={}, VERBOSE=0):
    if VERBOSE : print( "get_batch: " + func_name_id)
    try :
      if func_name_id in AUTHORIZED_FUNC :
        return globals()[func_name_id](ddict)   
      else : return []  
    except Exception as e:
      print(e)
      print("No batch  available")
      return []
```

Main reason is this creates a loose interface with history code, and adding new specialized function does not require changing the core part.

Is it a good way to implement interface in python, what are the potential issues I have to face?

There are resources available in the web, like this one:
http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ChangeInterface.html

But, the main question is:

**How to add new specialized functions 
  without changing the core interface function ?**

EDIT (based on comments):

Solution 1:
Create Based abstract class with method and inherit into the specialized functions. Negatives : Pb of class overload/maintenance.

Solution 2 :
Create 'indirection', ie above code.
Negatives: Usage of globals(),...

Comment: Looks like code smell to me... especially with `globals`.

Comment: What are the potential issues with this ?
How to do it in different way ?

Comment: You should probably maintain a dictionary lookup of functions you're supposed to run. You don't want users having unwanted access to other stuff through _your_ interface.

Comment: ok, thx, this is good point.
Do you another way to implement this interface ?

Comment: You could always consider the object oriented route with classes and whatnot, but I've never been one for those.

Comment: But, How to specialized the method without changing the interface code ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152890/discussion-between-tensor-and-cs).

Comment: Added my 2 cents as an answer.